# Delphi - comprehensive list of properties of object

Tags: delphi

For some particular object, I want the equivalent of copying (as text) the list of properties and events that appears in Delphi's Object Inspector.

My purpose is to be able to paste that into a spreadsheet, to be able to add notes to each item, add categorizations of properties that pertain to related functionality, or to compare to other objects (for example to align with inheritance ancestor or descendant).

So far as I know, Object Inspector doesn't have such a copy feature. So what's an alternative quick way to achieve this goal?

For what it's worth, I have Delphi's 1 through 7, 2007, XE, XE2, and Tokyo (of the latter, only Starter).

Clarification based on first few comments:

I do already know that items appearing on Object Inspector is the class's published properties, hence the information can be retrieved from the source files. However, the published properties may be distributed across multiple classes, and indeed multiple source files (due to inheritance), and the items themselves are not in a particularly convenient format. All surmountable. I simply hoped for a faster easier method, given that the Object Inspector's display is already so close to what I was looking for.

Comment: That would be the source code. What appears in the Object Inspector is what is in the `published` section of the class declaration.

Comment: @KenWhite  Yes I am aware that what's in the Object Inspector comes from source code. And the source code is text, and can be copied and pasted. It could even be parsed by a tool to put it in a more convenient format. And follow the inheritance logic to assemble all of the properties and not just those in the childmost unit. That's what I'm getting that, or some similar idea -- for all I know there might be a tool that taps into a service already provided by the IDE to parse Object Pascal, or whatever.

Comment: You can't ask for a tool recommendation here, according to the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Would whoever -1'ed my question please comment as to why? Is it off-topic for SO? Is it an already-solved question? What's the issue?

Comment: Where am I asking for a tool recommendation? I'm not asking "which tool is better for task X", I'm asking how to accomplish a task with respect to Delphi source code. I'm asking a method question.

Comment: I didn't write *for all I know there might be a tool* or *possibly an existing tool*. If you're not asking about a tool, then the solution is the source code.

Comment: OK, reference to "tool" removed from my original question.

Comment: OK. Reference to my original comment retained. The information you're requesting is in the published section of the class declaration in the source.

Comment: And I repeat that I already know where the info is located in the possibly numerous source files, in a format that's inconvenient. If you don't know of a way to assemble that info in the more convenient fashion that I requested, OK, fair enough, thanks for contributing your opinion that there is not better way.

Comment: You need to implement the same functionality as the Object Inspector. It works by using Runtime Type Information (RTTI). Basically you need to 1. enumerate all published properties of an object and 2. read their values. This might not be as easy as it sounds because of properties that are themselves objects. Also, there might be special editors registered for a given class type + property type in the IDE. But reading up on RTTI samples will get you a lot further.

Comment: @dummzeuch: for properties that are objects themselves, one could use recursion. Or just ignore their properties and only list the top level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment, I am writing this as an answer.
I think gwideman is asking for a way to copy inside Delphi's IDE, and without any coding with RTTI.

To an extend this is possible. What you need to do is simply select an object and copy (Ctrl-C). After that you can paste it to any text editor or even Excel. It should be something like this:

```
object Button1: TButton
  Left = 60
  Top = 510
  Width = 80
  Height = 25
  Anchors = [akLeft, akBottom]
  Caption = 'Save'
  Enabled = False
  TabOrder = 0
  OnClick = Button1Click
end
```

Notice that even the event handlers are included.

You may also notice that the list is rather short. This is because properties that have the default values are skipped. This can be a problem if you need all properties. But if you just want to comment your settings this saves time and is the best.

If you need the whole list of published properties, you can easily get it in Delphi's help. Like [`TSpeedButton`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/_!!MEMBERTYPE_Properties_Buttons_TSpeedButton_14_Published_Properties.html).

Finally, if you right-click on the form and click "View as Text", you can get the properties of the form and all its objects.

Comment: That's a helpful suggestion! I'd forgotten about form text mode/dfm. Extending your answer, for the component under study, one could set all of the properties (in Object Inspector) so that all are persisted in the form. Not ideal, but best no-code method thus far. As for Help -- yes, but I encounter components that are documented somewhere other than Help (because Help platform is a moving target), or docs are incomplete, or not documented at all.

Comment: I don't think that would work. If the set value equals to the default value, Delphi removes it. Even if you add the line in "View as text" mode, it is removed after switching to "View as form".

Comment: Right -- you would have to change each property to a value other than the default so it will get persisted.